# Populate WPF C# DataGrid ComboBox ItemsSource Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a grid that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. Basically, each item in the collection contains a different flag, that has different options. For example, ID #1 has a value that can be set to ON or OFF, and ID #2 has a value that can be set to ENGLISH or SPANISH.

So, I need to set the `ComboBox ItemsSource` dynamically, based on the ID (which is the first column in the grid).

What would be a good way to implement this?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: Some flags require a text input rather than a selection. So this would need to be implemented into the same column.

**EDIT2**: I was able to do this by creating a switch and returning the specific list based on the ID, and setting it as the ItemSource Binding.

Comment: The model which has the flags should also have a list with available options. This would be the easiest way to go about this. You can then bind the selected value of the combobox to that item.

Comment: Create a DataGridTemplateColumns with a Style that contains a DataTrigger that sets the ItemsSource based on the Id property?

Comment: @mm8 Could you provide an example of how to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating a switch and returning the specific list based on the ID, and setting it as the ItemSource Binding.

Comment: So you no longer need an example?

Comment: @mm8 No, I got it. Thank you